# How to disable the suffix "-scaled" which is being added at the end of each uploaded image?

Tags: images, uploads

I don't know why, but now, Wordpress is adding a suffix "-scaled" at the end of each newly uploaded image.

[image]

And, instead of keeping the original image link, it changes it to the "-scaled" version:

[image]

I found the culprit in `/wp-admin/includes/image.php` which has this:

```
        if ( ! is_wp_error( $resized ) ) {
            // Append "-scaled" to the image file name. It will look like "my_image-scaled.jpg".
            // This doesn't affect the sub-sizes names as they are generated from the original image (for best quality).
            $saved = $editor->save( $editor->generate_filename( 'scaled' ) );
```

How to get rid of this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

This plugin helped me: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-smushit/
It allows to make max size of images larger than 2560x2560.

After installing go to Bulk Smush's settings and there toggle on "Resize my full size images". I just set Max width and height 9999x9999

As a result suffix "-scaled" won't be added anymore.

PS I found one more plugin with the similar purpose, but didn't check it since the first helped: [Disable "BIG Image" Threshold](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-big-image-threshold/)

To learn more about the cause go to: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2019/10/09/introducing-handling-of-big-images-in-wordpress-5-3/

Answer (score 2):

#### How to disable this behaviour?

Add this to your `functions.php`:

```php
add_filter( 'big_image_size_threshold', '__return_false' );
```

#### How does it work?

When a new image is uploaded, WordPress will detect if it is a “big” image by checking if its height or width exceeds the big_image threshold. The default threshold value is **2560px**, filterable with the new [`big_image_size_threshold`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/big_image_size_threshold/) filter.

If the image's height or width is above this threshold, it will be scaled down, with the threshold being used for maximum height and max. width value. The scaled down image will be used as the largest available size.

In this case, the original image file is stored in the uploads directory and its name is stored in another array key in the [image meta array](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_metadata/): original_image. To be able to always get the path to an originally uploaded image a new function [`wp_get_original_image_path()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_original_image_path/) was introduced.

Source: [Introducing handling of big images in WordPress 5.3 by Justin Ahinon](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2019/10/09/introducing-handling-of-big-images-in-wordpress-5-3/)